# How set a spending and description in a txt file using Python?

Tags: python

I want a result like this: 
`Food| 200.00|
Eletricity|150.00|`

But always return error, I know I can't concatenate string and float, so what is the best solution for this?

Thank you in advance

````
while True:
    fileGastos = open("Gastos.txt", "a+")
    fileGastos1 = open("Gastos.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    lerFile = fileGastos1.read()
    gDescri = input("Descrição: ")
    if gDescri in lerFile:
        while True:
            print("A descrição ja existe, tente outra")
            gDescri = input("Descrição: ")
            if gDescri not in lerFile:
                break
    gValor = float(input("Valor: "))
    fileGastos.write(gDescri + "|")
    fileGastos.write(gValor)
    fileGastos.write("\n")
    print("Continue registering?")
    print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
    choice = input()
    if choice == '2':
        break
    elif choice != '1':
        print("Invalid option")
        print("Continue registering?")
        print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
        choice = input()
        fileGastos.close()```
````

Comment: Show us the **whole** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting the float to string when printing it. 
here is the edited code

```
while True:
    fileGastos = open("Gastos.txt", "a+")
    fileGastos1 = open("Gastos.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    lerFile = fileGastos1.read()
    gDescri = input("Descrição: ")
    if gDescri in lerFile:
        while True:
            print("A descrição ja existe, tente outra")
            gDescri = input("Descrição: ")
            if gDescri not in lerFile:
                break
    gValor = float(input("Valor: "))
    fileGastos.write(gDescri + "|")
    fileGastos.write(str(gValor)) # Here float is converted again to string
    fileGastos.write("\n")
    print("Continue registering?")
    print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
    choice = input()
    if choice == '2':
        break
    elif choice != '1':
        print("Invalid option")
        print("Continue registering?")
        print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
        choice = input()
        fileGastos.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**the solution is cast the value to string**

```
  fileGastos.write(str(gValor))
```